# SSIS Output XML to UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014\SSIS.

I have a Data Flow Task that contains a OLE Source and Flat File Destination.
The OLE Source executes a SQL Command:

```sql
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
                   DEFAULT 'http://www.example.com'
                    )

SELECT @XMLOutput =
(
SELECT  
ISNULL(RTRIM(T1.[JobID]),'') as JobId,
FROM   [tblJobFile] T1   
FOR XML PATH('Job'),TYPE,ROOT('JobLoader')
)

SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

As you can see I'm setting the output to UTF-8.

In addition, the Flat File destination has the Unicode box ticked.

However, if I open one of the XML files created in Notepad++ it states the encoding is UCS-2 LE BOM, not UTF-8.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that SQL Server has no support for UTF-8, period (well, 2019 will have some, but that still won't affect this scenario). Adding an XML processing directive won't suddenly make it so. The `XML` type always uses UTF-16. I'm not sure whether you can (easily) do encoding conversions in SSIS -- it's certainly always possible with difficulty (as it can run arbitrary .NET code), but it will have to happen outside SQL Server in any case. Try making the return type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` -- SSIS may be unwilling to convert `XML` at all.

Comment: That is the case in, I believe, all environments, not just SQL Server. When an XML is loaded into memory, it's stored using whatever rules the environment has for strings. Only when it's output to a file the declared encoding comes into play, and only when the thing that does the outputting is aware of XML business (e.g. an XML serializer). Your piece of code returns a string, it's not XML anymore, and the thing that will output that *string* into a file will only convert the entire string from the environment's encoding for strings (UTF-16) to the encoding of the file (UTF-16).

Comment: I missed that the return type already *is* `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (assuming you're using `@XMLOutputChar` as the result passed to SSIS) so that last part of my previous comment can be ignored. The rest still applies -- SSIS receives the value as UTF-16 and stores it as such as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks to you both, it helps.